# Where can I find the history of mathematical symbols in the order they were introduced?

Tags: self-learning, math-history

Lately I've wondered how I could learn about the history of mathematical symbols in the order they were introduced in the chain of human being. For example the symbol for Union in set theory (∪) is taught as if it were universal, but the date of it's first inscription is obscure.

I would like to read something which shows the timeline of historical unfolding of mathematical symbols (their use and application) to frame it within it's historical background so to provide a more rapid introduction to everything, including computers in the present day.

PS: I am vision impaired and struggle with symbols because text-to-speech programs do not vocalize them. However, I have no problem hearing sentences. However, the time is out of joint, sentences surrounding symbols alone (historical knowledge) is tricky to find. I am looking for a great list or a great book.

Thank you

Comment: Not strictly in historical order, but I have greatly benefited from Cajori's "A History of Mathematical Notations".  I don't know how well this would play with text-to-speech. 
 https://www.amazon.com/History-Mathematical-Notations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486677664

Comment: See on-line: [Tripod](https://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out Florian Cajori, "A History of Mathematical Notations."

[https://www.amazon.com/History-Mathematical-Notations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486677664](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486677664)

This question might also get good answers on the History of Science and Math stackexchange.

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but the format for this text in pdf form is very poorly scanned. I wish there was something a lot more compact.